# Pyspark: Multithreading over multiple nodes

Tags: multithreading, pyspark

I am still very new to Pyspark and try to search this around but find nothing that directly answers this question. I am running some job to decoding large amount of URLs and currently it is multithreaded on a single node (by default), just wondering if it is possible to have multithreading within each node across multiple of them (spark + multithreading) to further accelerate the job? Can I include multithreading as part of Pyspark udf function? Thanks!

Comment: Will you be able to add some code block on how you are performing it currently and provide some additional details of your cluster configuration ? This might help someone in answering your question more precisely. And Welcome to StackOverflow!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Like Joby said, could you provide a more concrete example/ reproducible code snippets for us to better help you?

With that being said, [FAIR scheduler mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#fair-scheduler-pools) of spark application and [this video](https://databricks.com/session/continuous-application-with-fair-scheduler) is a good start for you read.